# Positioning of price range slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have just started learning html, css and js and I recently had to create a price slider range in a website that will be reasonable in it.

I would like to know how can I reposition it. I've copied the entire code from this link http://jqueryui.com/slider/#range however, the positioning is at the top of the web browser and it takes up the entire width of the browser as well 
[image]
Is there anyway I can make it  like adidas web page does it?   http://shop.adidas.com.sg/men.html 
At the side of the web browser and the size is kinda small ?

terribly sorry if I sound extremely dumb but I have no experienced in this.

Comment: Please try something first before expecting someone to come and save the day for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visit https://jsfiddle.net/vexsc7d8/1/

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Slider - Range slider</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
/**** In style.css add class .container { float:left; width:200px;} ****/
  <script>
   $(function() {
   $( "#slider-range" ).slider({
      range: true,
      min: 0,
      max: 500,
      values: [ 75, 300 ],
      slide: function( event, ui ) {
        $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + ui.values[ 0 ] + " - $" + ui.values[ 1 ] );
      }
    });
    $( "#amount" ).val( "$" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 0 ) +
  " - $" + $( "#slider-range" ).slider( "values", 1 ) );
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<p>
  <label for="amount">Price range:</label>
  <input type="text" id="amount" readonly style="border:0; color:#f6931f;    font-weight:bold;">
</p>
<div class="container"> 
    <div id="slider-range"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would hazard a guess you just haven't put it within a div and therefore it's taking up 100% of page body instead of 100% of a div sized as you need.

Hope this helps, just a last minute idea for you before I go home from work lol

Regards
Liam

Answer (score 0):

to shape the way a component looks you'll need to use CSS.

- 1 option is to create a div tag around the slider html element and use css to change its side using with width property.

```css
#divContainingSlider {
  width: 100px;
}
```